# Module lazy loading of angular 4 not working with Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to use Angular as frontend and Laravel as backend and I have created my Angular project with lazy loaded modules and used webpack to do so. 
However, when I use my webpack-dev-server the lazy loading works find and when I use my build files and serve using Laravel it throws the error like this

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

`Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptComplete (polyfills.js:104) [angular]
    at HTMLScriptElement.wrapFn (polyfills.js:8558) [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (app.js:4091) [angular]`

The *chunk* generation works fine. It generates files like `0.chunk.js` and on...

Thanks

Comment: What do you see in dev tools -> network? which url is there?

Comment: there is some template error please check carefully

Comment: Thank you @VolodymyrBilyachat for pointing that out, the URL is wrong the rest of the file's URL is correct like _assets/app.js_ but for the chunk files the url is _/0.chunk.js_, so how can I solve this?

Comment: @AbhilashRathod are you using angular cli?

Comment: also what is expected url for chunk?

Comment: Thank you @VolodymyrBilyachat, it was URL problem, in the chunk generation I added the property called `publicPath : /assets/` and it worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other build files used the path to *assets*, 
So added that same path for chunk file generation in the `webpack.config.js`. I thought the path property used for all the generated file.

the code goes like this.

`output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
        publicPath: 'assets/',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/')
    }`

Comment: I have the same issue and i use your suggestion..but stil not work.
[https://pastebin.com/68p41KTZ] This is my webpack.js.
Please help me.. Thanks